# How can I check if a user is using a keyboard or mouse for copy-paste in an Office Word add-in?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I have developed a tool that includes a copy button for users to easily copy content. The purpose of this feature is to track usage. However, I did not block users from using the copy function for convenience. I would like to know if it is possible to detect whether a user has used keyboard or mouse shortcuts to copy and paste content. Do you know if this functionality is supported by Word add-ins?

I used the following method, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'v') {
        console.log("Paste Detected via Keyboard");
    }
});

document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event) {
    console.log("Right Click Detected - Potentially a Paste via Mouse");
});
```